# Entity Framework returning different value for varbinary type in database

Tags: c#, arrays, sql-server, entity-framework, varbinarymax

I'm a newbie to `C#` and `EF` so apologies if I get some terminology incorrect as I'm currently fixing some code from a developer who wrote our `Web APIs` but is not available.

In summary we have a `JAVA` front end that uploads `PDF` files and stores them in our `SQL Server` database as `varbinary(max)`. When the `JAVA` web app downloads the `PDF` it calls a database function which returns the `varbinary` data into a `byte[]` variable and then the `JAVA` web app is able to file stream it and save as a `PDF` no problems.

The database value for the file data, as well as what it returned by the function that returns the `varbinary(max)` column as well as what is stored in the `byte[]` that is used in `JAVA` and then converted to a string, are all the same and looks like :

```
"0x255044462D312E360D25E2E3CFD30D0A34372030206F626A0D3C3C2F414442455F46696C6C5369676E496E666F3C3C2F56657273696F6E203130302F666F726D4..."
```

which from what I can tell is the format for `varbinary` data.

In the `Web API` which uses `EF`, the same function is modelled in the `EF` Model and it appears as a `Complex Type`, and the `Filedata` column is of type `Binary` which according to `MS docs` this is correct:

(https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/data/adonet/sql-server-data-type-mappings?redirectedfrom=MSDN)

In the C# model, the `Filedata` is defined as :

```
public byte[] FileData { get; set; }
```

There is a `Controller` that returns the data from the function as follows:

```
[HttpGet]
public IHttpActionResult FileAttachment_Get(string FileAttachmentID)
{
   using (TSTDBContext dbContext = new TSTDBContext())
   {
       Guid FileAttachmentGUID = new Guid(FileAttachmentID);
       var entity = dbContext.FileAttachment_Get(FileAttachmentGUID).SingleOrDefault();
       if (entity != null)
       {
            /*var str = System.Text.Encoding.Default.GetString(entity.FileData);*/
            return Ok(new { results = entity });
       }
       else
       {
           return NotFound();
       }
   }
}
```

The entity variable contains the `Filedata` value which we can then return in our Web API to be used by our mobile apps to display `PDFs`. The returned value is different to what is in the database and looks like:

```
"JVBERi0xLjYNJeLjz9MNCjQ3IDAgb2JqDTw8L0FEQkVfRmlsbFNpZ25JbmZvPDwvVmVyc2lvbiAxMDAvZm9ybUlEKDY0OTFiNDYzLTA2MGEtNGU1Yy05NmYyLTljMThkMTZlNDlhZik+Pi9NZXRhZGF0YSA1NSAwIFIvT0NQcm9wZXJ0aWVzPDwvRDw8L09OWzU2IDAgUl0vT3JkZXJbXS9SQkdyb3Vwc1tdPj4vT0NHc1s1NiAwI..."
```

When we use this for the `PDF` file the `PDF` file is corrupted. There is other data that is returned by the function and the data is correct, but none of the data is of type `varbinary`. The `varbinary` data is the only field we are having issues with and is returned different to what is stored in the database.

The commented code above that converts it to a string also displays the different data.

My question is why is `EF` bringing back different data to what is in the database for the `varbinary(max) column`?

I hope I have explained enough but if you need more details please let me know.

Thanks.

Comment: This has nothing to do with EF. The *action* returns a JSON string containing the BASE64-encoded file contents in the `results` string property. If you wanted to return the file directly you should have used `return File(fileContents)`, where `fileContents` are the actual contents of the `varbinary` field, not the entity

Comment: If you do want to send the JSON string back, you'll have to decode them on the client side. How you do that depends on the client, language and library used. If the client uses JSON.NET it's possible to specify that the `result` property, or whatever property holds the binary data, is a `byte[]`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As others have mentioned that you are returning an entity and MVC controller is returning base 64 in the response.  If you want to get the file you can try the following code, slightly adjusted from your sample.

```
[HttpGet, Route("api/files/{FileAttachmentID}")]
    public IHttpActionResult FileAttachment_Get(string FileAttachmentID)
    {
        using (TSTDBContext dbContext = new TSTDBContext())
        {
            Guid FileAttachmentGUID = new Guid(FileAttachmentID);
            var entity = dbContext.FileAttachment_Get(FileAttachmentGUID).SingleOrDefault();
            if (entity != null)
            {
                using (var stream = new MemoryStream())
                {
                    var result = new HttpResponseMessage(HttpStatusCode.OK)
                    {
                        Content = new ByteArrayContent(entity.Content)//this is your varbinary value
                    };
                    result.Content.Headers.ContentDisposition = new System.Net.Http.Headers.ContentDispositionHeaderValue("attachment")
                    {
                        FileName = entity.Name
                    };
                    result.Content.Headers.ContentType = new MediaTypeHeaderValue("application/octet-stream");
                    var response = ResponseMessage(result);
                    return response;
                }
            }
            else
            {
                return NotFound();
            }
        }
```

Comment: sorry took me a little while to get back to this. Was on a trip to the US then had to cope with all the corona things to get back to Australia... but this worked!! Thanks very much. One thing, I had to remove "Route("api/files/{FileAttachmentID}")]". Keeping it there caused the error: No HTTP resource was found that matches the request URI. Removing it though allowed the file to download via the browser.

Answer (score 0):

The `MVC Controller` Response is probably `base64` Encoded, so you will need to use `base64` Decoding in your client before creating the PDF.